# In Xpath, Can I use '=' operator to link a sub xpath query?

Tags: xml, database, xpath

I just learned xpath in the class and have a question from my mind.

I make up this question

```
<student>
 <name>...</name>
 <course>...</course>
</student>

<professor>
 <name>...</name>
 <course>...</course>
</professor>
```

If I wish to find students which are taught by professor Mike.Can I do this?

> /student[course=/professor[name=Mike]/course]/name

If it is not legal, is there any other methods I can achieve this query?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing wrong with your XPath is that you'd need to quote the `Mike`, but the example input you've given isn't XML because it isn't well-formed - it has more than one root-level element.  If you make it well-formed:

```
<root>
 <student>
  <name>...</name>
  <course>...</course>
 </student>

 <professor>
  <name>...</name>
  <course>...</course>
 </professor>
</root>
```

then `/root/student[course=/root/professor[name='Mike']/course]/name` is fine, and will return the name elements from every student whose course matches any course taught by any professor named "Mike".